# how to write MapRoute mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, maproute

I have a api controller :

```
public class ExchangesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<ExchangesTrade> GetTrades(long tid)
    {
```

I want to be able to call it from browser like `/api/USD/trades.json?tid=5`

How should I write "routes.MapRoute" in my RouteConfig ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, routes.MapRoute will add routes for a traditional MVC app, if you want to add routes for your web api you need to add Http routes using MapHttpRoute on your web api HttpConfiguration routes.

In your web api config, you can add a URI path mapping extension like this:

```
config.Formatters
      .JsonFormatter
      .MediaTypeMappings
      .Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json"));
```

Add a route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ExchangesRouteWithExtensions",
        routeTemplate: "api/USD/{action}.{ext}/{tid}",
        defaults: new { controller = Exchanges, tid = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Then access you endpoint like this:

```
api/USD/trades.json?tid=5
```